# PHP if to run script on a specific ip address

Tags: php, if-statement

Is there a way to add an if so that some script will only run for users using a specific ip address.

Comment: And for reference: [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3003145)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use if.

If your ip address is : 111.111.111.111

```
if($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]=='111.111.111.111'){
//run only my ip
}
```